# In Java, starting a test in selenium with the DefaultSelenium object how do I find which browser the test is running on?

Tags: java, selenium, cross-browser

Consider a simple DefaultSelenium object

```
DefaultSelenium sel = new 
      DefaultSelenium("http://localhost:8080/myapp",4444,"*iexplore","/myAppLevel1");
```

Now my server is set with the option of -forcedBrowserMode "*firefox" in the command line when I start it up.  However, I have 2 different batch files to start the Server, one forced in firefox, one forced to IE.  FYI, the -forcedBrowserMode overrides the settings within of the instantiated java object.

The problem is from java, I can't seem to find a way to determine which browser my DefaultSelenium object is running on... I was thinking something like:

```
sel.getBrowserName();
```

But nothing like that exists.  Are there any other creative ways of doing this?

I need to know because with a GWT web application, to click on a button you need to do it differently based on the browser.  As well, you may wonder why I even use the -forcedBrowserMode, because then I can use custom setup firefox/ie installs to test on.

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can get the browser by executing some JavaScript, for example verify `navigator.userAgent` or any browser specific object, for example `document.defaultView` will be null in IE and not null in FF, something like this:

```
DefaultSelenium sel = ...
String res = sel.getEval("document.defaultView ? false : true");
boolean isIE = "true".equals(res);
```